# Android Chrome Custom Tabs add Copy Link to options menu

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

How to add 'Copy link' option to Chrome Custom Tabs options menu in Android. Adding custom menu items in CustomTabs is like this.

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

String menuItemTitle = App.s(R.string.share);
PendingIntent menuItemPendingIntent = createPendingIntentShare(url);
customTabsIntent.addMenuItem(menuItemTitle, menuItemPendingIntent);
```

I want to add Copy Link option just like Twitter do in his app browser. I am not sure how I can copy link to Clipboard in CustomTabs.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String url = intent.getDataString();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Copy link pressed. URL = " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Here you can copy the URL to the clipboard
    }
}
```

Register it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
</receiver>
```

Use this method to launch the Custom Tab:

```
private void launchCustomTab() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver.class);

    String label = "Copy link";
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            .addMenuItem(label, pendingIntent)
            .build();

    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse("http://www.google.it"));
}
```

Comment: Heres a link to a BroadcastReceiver implementation that copies the link to the clipboard: https://gist.github.com/andreban/ccccade793f63ace207b